# Why does list become empty after returning it from function?

Tags: python, list, function

When returning a list of tuples from a class method, the returned list becomes empty.

I have tried printing the list to sys.stderr just before returning it (here, it contains all the tuples) and after receiving it on the calling side (here, all tuples are gone). I have also tried changing data type to a tuple of tuples, but the problem remains. I have double checked so that I am returning the correct variable. There are no similar variable names, but I have also tried changing the variable name without success.

I am running my code on Python 3 in Codeingame's environment. This is the specific challenge I am coding for: https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/tic-tac-toe

```py
class Boardstate:
    def get_valid_moves(self):
        valid_moves = []
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                sq = self.squares[row][col]
                sq_valid_moves = [
                    (row*3 + j, col*3 + i) for (j, i) in sq.get_valid_moves()
                ]
                valid_moves.extend(sq_valid_moves)
        print(valid_moves, file=sys.stderr)
        return valid_moves

valid_moves = temp_state.get_valid_moves() #temp_state is an instance of Boardstate
print(valid_moves, file=sys.stderr)
```

I expect to see the same list of tuples outside the class method as I see inside it before returning.

Comment: Variables can only reach the area in which they are defined, which is called scope. Think of it as the area of code where variables can be used. Python supports global variables (usable in the entire program) and local variables. By default, all variables declared in a function are local variables.

Comment: Someone is more likely to identify your problem if you can post a [mre].

Comment: Can it be a problem with their interpreter? The code looks good to me (those all are lists, not generators) but their online interpreter could limit something.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I know about scope. but I am as you can see returning the locally defined list for it to be used outside of the scope of get_valid_moves. I suppose it could be a problem with their interpreter, but they have a huge user base so the problem should have been discovered earlier I think...

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding self to valid_moves like this:

```
class Boardstate:
    def get_valid_moves(self):
        self.valid_moves = []
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                sq = self.squares[row][col]
                sq_valid_moves = [
                    (row*3 + j, col*3 + i) for (j, i) in sq.get_valid_moves()
                ]
                self.valid_moves.extend(sq_valid_moves)
        print(self.valid_moves, file=sys.stderr)
        return self.valid_moves
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried what you said but it still results in an empty list after returned.